# Unity hub cannot install open JDK

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am worried about this little problem: I am creating a mobile game in unity and I need java openJDK, but I cannot install it via unity hub, I have already installed open JDK on oracle website (but version 14, which is not compatible with unity - error message says), where can I download the right version winhout singing to oracle or paying it?

Or does anyone has a tip how to fix the hub installing issue?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Later I noticed that my antivirus is blocking installation. What you could do is, temporarily disable your antivirus and add Open JDK module from Unity hub. It will work. Don't forget to enable your antivirus after your installation completes.

Answer (score 0):

On windows - right click your unity version folder (in my case `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.1.0f1\Editor`)  and uncheck read only then click apply. If this doesnt work,right click again ,go to security tab select ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES user and check Full control.